# Can we check if a Person Account was enabled in Salesforce Organization using Flow?

Tags: visual-workflow, process-automation

Can we use a flow or process builder to check if the Person Account was enabled in Salesforce Organization? If yes, how? I would like to make a decision in my automation based on whether person account is enabled or not. How do we check this using flow or process builder?

Any help would be appreciable.

Thank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After enabling Person Accounts feature, the field on Account `isPersonAccount` will be available.

In a flow, you could query the [FieldDefinition](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_fielddefinition.htm) object to see if this field is returned as a check for whether Person Accounts is enabled.

It'd essentially amount to this SOQL

`SELECT count() FROM FieldDefinition WHERE EntityDefinitionId = 'Account' AND DeveloperName = 'IsPersonAccount'`

This would be a [Get Records](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_elements_data_get.htm&type=5) element in the flow

[image]

From that query, you could then use a decision element to check if the variable from that element is null which would indicate the org does not have Person Accounts enabled.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You can't do so directly in a Flow, because the Flow would end up having a dependency on the Person Account feature, and thus could not be installed in an org without Person Accounts. You need to write one or more Apex Actions (InvocableMethod) to deal with an optional feature like this.